# MongoDB Compass always connects to local instead of remote db via tunnel

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-compass

I try to connect with MongoDB Compass via ssh tunnel.
It worked before but now when I do it, it always connects to my local MongoDB instance instead of my remote one. Please have a look at the pictures below which show my settings. pretty sure it was also before like this but somehow now it connect to the wrong DB. When I connect manually via ssh (using exactly those credentials) I can see that the data is different.

What am I missing here?

[connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/edgkI.png)
[connection2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/alptU.png)

Comment: Is the identity file located in the directory from which you are launching compass?

Comment: Its in my home directory and I pick it via the file picker, so I assume this is not the issue. else I guess there would be some access denied or file not found error.

Comment: Still could not figure it out. I am now using the secure pipes app to create the ssh tunnel instead of mongodb compass and this works fine

Comment: Could be a compass issue. What is the documentation that you are following that explains how to do what you are trying to do?

Comment: I do it like described here (also matches the compass docs): https://medium.com/@kommradhomer/how-to-connect-mongodb-compass-via-ssh-tunnel-f6ecba22deed
I did update compass recently so maybe its a new bug

Comment: Hey @solaire did you figured this out? I have the same error (Robo 3T too). I am trying to connect to remote replica set, but it connects to local. In `/etc/hosts/` I have `mongo-1 127.0.0.1`, etc. Thanks!

Comment: I used the mac software secure pipes for some time to work around this but with the newer versions of compass it worked again.